# module extending other modules in Ruby

Tags: ruby, inheritance, module

I have read quite a few answers here in this regards, but I still cant figure out why the following doesn't work

```rb
module A
  def a
    puts 'hi'
  end
end

module B
  extend A
end

class C
  extend B
  def b
    a
  end
end
C.new.b # undefined local variable or method `a' for #<C:...
```

I've also tried with:

```rb
module B
  def self.included(recipient)
    recipient.extend A
  end
end
```

Hoping `C` will get extended (but I guess the hierarchy is then wrong)

**Important**: The Problem is that I have a module that requires to be `extended` [memoist](https://github.com/matthewrudy/memoist), and I want to add some functionality to it.

How can I achieve that and why is the first example not working?

Comment: Also see http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/15/include-vs-extend-in-ruby/

Comment: @Kris yes I did read it already, but first that is a case of a module define within another (not sure it's important) and more than that, it's not about extending (in any way) a method that has to be imported as "extended" (requirement for memoist)

Comment: I like that you've created a standalone example.  It may be too far from reality, however.  I think you may need to give us an example that uses Memoist, so that we can see the actual problem you are having.

Comment: A module which is included in a class or another module is usually called a mixin. When you use `extend` it will create class, not instance, methods. Although you can also create class methods via `include` too using a bit of extra magic by the way of the `included` method which can then `extend` the target class with a nested module by convention called `ClassMethods`.

Answer (score 4):

`extends` adds the methods from the module passed as argument as 'class methods'. What you're looking for is `include`, which adds methods from (in this case) `A` module as instance methods, just like you want it to:

```
module A
  def a
    puts 'hi'
  end
end

module B
  include A
end

class C
  include B
  def b
    a
  end
end
C.new.b
# hi
```

Comment: Sorry but class C needs to be extended by module A as I put in the question, this is important. (Is a requirement of memoist, I don't want to extend on why this is so, but it is).

Comment: This does answer the question.

Comment: @estani please clarify then. You want to have methods from module `A` as instance methods as well as class methods?
Maybe you should describe what you're trying to achieve using `Memoist`?

Answer (score 2):

Recall that if a module `M1` is `included` or `extended` (or `prepended`) by a module `M2`, `M1`'s instance methods are brought into `M2`, either as instance methods (if including) or as module methods (if extending). If `M1` contains module methods (methods invoked on `M1`) they are skipped over by both `include` and `extend`. As classes are modules, this applies when `M2` is a class.

```
module M1
  def i() end
  def self.m() end
end

M1.instance_methods
  #=> [:i] 
M1.methods(false)
  #=> [:m]
```

```
module M2; end

M2.extend M1
M2.instance_methods
  #=> []
M2.methods & [:i, :m]
  #=> [:i]
```

```
module M3; end

M3.include M1
M3.instance_methods
  #=> [:i]
M3.methods & [:i, :m]
  #=> []
```

We see that neither `M2` nor `M3` contains a method `:m`. Now consider the following.

```
module A
  def a
    puts 'hi'
  end
end

module B
  extend A
end

B.instance_methods
  #=> []
B.methods & [:a]
  #=> [:a]
```

As expected, `B` contains no instance methods and its module methods include `:a`. From the earlier discussion it follows that including or extending `B` into another module (or class) `C` brings *no instance methods or methods* into `C`.

To add to the functionality of `A`, `B` must `include` (or `prepend`) `A`.

```
module B
  include A
  def b
    puts 'ho'
  end
end

B.instance_methods
  #=> [:b, :a] 
B.methods & [:a, :b]
  #=> []
```

`C` may then `include` or `extend` `B`, depending on requirements.

One may ask whether there is any reason to define module methods if they are disregarded when the module is included or extended by another module. The answer is that they are simply helper methods that behave as functions in non-OOP languages. An example is the module [Math](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Math.html), which contains module methods only. They are therefore invoked on the module; for example,

```
Math.sqrt(2)
  #=> 1.4142135623730951
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all your example is not entirely valid. A module that is extended doesn't add instance methods by default. Your `A` module should look something like this:

```
module Memoist
  def self.extended(mod)
    mod.include InstanceMethods
  end

  module InstanceMethods
    def a
      puts 'hi'
    end
  end
end
```

You can `extend Memoist` in an `extended`, `included` or `excluded` callback. This works as long as you're adding to the interface. The callbacks are triggered after your module is extended, included or prepended. **This means that if you want to extend an existing method using `super` this won't work since the original is called before your version.**

```
module YourMemoist
  # Depending on how you want to incorporate your module into the class
  # you can use one of the following: 
  def self.extended(mod)
    mod.extend Memoist
  end

  # def self.included(mod)
  #   mod.extend Memoist
  # end

  # def self.prepended(mod)
  #   mod.extend Memoist
  # end

  # ...
end

class C
  extend MemoistHelper # or include, prepend
end

C.new.a #=> prints hi
C.singleton_class.ancesotrs #=> [#<Class:C>, Memoist, YourMemoist, ...]
```

If you do want to use the `super` keyword things are going to be a bit more difficult. Since the `Memoist` module needs to be extended first. One way of doing this by including the module into your own, so you can override them. Pretty simple so far. However `Memoist` might have an `extended` callback defined (to add instance methods), which is not triggered when we include the module in our own. So we need to call this manually.

```
module YourMemoist
  include Memoist

  def self.extended(mod)
    Memoist.send(:extended, mod) # using #send to call private method
    # If you want to add your own instance methods add them after the
    # above call (as shown in the Memoist module).
  end

  # ...
end

class C
  extend MemoistHelper
end

C.new.a #=> prints hi
C.singleton_class.ancesotrs #=> [#<Class:C>, YourMemoist, Memoist, ...]
```